# static member inside class c++ undefined reference

Tags: c++

Why this code is giving me an error that undefined reference to student::count. I am using static count and I know that static members are by default is 0 but dont know why giving me an error. Please explain me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{

static int count;
string name;


public:

    Student(){
        count++;
        cout<<"I am  student"<<count<<endl;

    }
    int getCount() const
    {

        return count;
    }

    void setCount(int x){
        count=x;

    }


};

int main(){

Student stud[20];


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to do `int Student::count;`

Comment: "Giving me an error" There are lots of kinds of errors. The more specific you are, the more quickly otherx can help you.

Comment: please also tell me about static constant? I just want to understand that

Comment: thanks i got it now i forgot to use int Student::count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *no* definition of `Student::count`, violating the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). Put a definition in one, and only one, translation unit.

Note that if `static int count;` *was* a definition, static members would be almost impossible to use. You'd wind up with a definition each time you included the header file, making the one definition rule almost impossible to comply with.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `static int count;` in your header means: Compiler, somewhere you will find a variable scoped to this class, it will be a `int` and will be nammed `count`.

Now, you need to actually instantiate (define) your variable somewhere. Maybe in your case, adding `int Student::count;` to your main file would be fine.